# Parser Combinator ^^ with Optional Values

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm trying to modify an example from [DSLs in Action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/).

Originally, this code was used to parse `items` followed by `account`.

```
  lazy val order: Parser[Order] = 
    items ~ account_spec ^^ {
      case i ~ a => Order(i, a)
    }
```

The following text could be parsed with the above parser:

```
(100 IBM shares to buy at max 45) for account "A1234
------------- item -------------  ------ account ----
```

But, I'd like to add `FOO` and an optional `not` values to the parser:

```
  lazy val order: Parser[Order] = 
    items <~ "FOO" ~> ("not"?) ~ account_spec ^^ {
      case i ~ n ~ a => println(n); Order(i, a)
    }
```

`FOO` must follow `account` and, optionally, `not` will follow.

Example:

```
(100 IBM shares to buy at max 45) FOO not for account "A1234
---------- item ------------------ --- --- ------ account ----
```

However, the above code gives me this compile-time error:

```
[WARNING] ....\OrderDsl.scala:19: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to 
expected type;
[WARNING]  found   : ch8.trading.semantic.dsl.OrderDsl.~[a,b]
[WARNING]  required: ch8.trading.semantic.dsl.AST.Items
[WARNING]       case i ~ n ~ a => println(n); Order(i, a)
[WARNING]                  ^
```

How can I modify the `case` statement to support parsing an *optional* "not" value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a <~ "FOO" ~> b` means "ignore results of parsers `"FOO"` and `b` and return the result of `a`".

Rewrite your method like this:

```
lazy val order: Parser[Order] = 
  items ~ opt("FOO") ~ opt("not") ~ account_spec ^^ {
    case i ~ _ ~ n ~ a => println(n); Order(i, a)
  }
```

General mnemonic for `~>` and `<~`: you can ignore from start to operator or from operator to end, but not the middle part of expression.

Comment: Thanks, @senia. Your answer cleared up my mis-use of `~>` and `<~` together.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Actually you could use `items ~ (opt("FOO") ~> opt("not") ~ account_spec) ^^ { case i ~ (n ~ a) => ...}`.

Comment: If we added `case i ~ foo ~ n ...`, is it true that `foo` could only equal `None` and `Some("FOO")`? My pattern match on `foo match { case None  => ... case Some("FOO")` is telling me that the `match` is non-exhaustive.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: yes, but compiler knows only the type of `foo`. You should use `foo.isDefined`.